# Convergence at positive integers implies converges uniformly on compact subsets

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $(f_n)$ be sequence of bounded analytic functiona from complement of closed unit disk to itself. I want to show if for every positive integer $k$ we have $f_n(k)$ converges, then $f$ uniformly converges on every compact subsets on right half plane. I was trying to use definition but didn't work.

Comment: use $g_n(w)=\frac{1}{f_n(1/w)}, 0<|w|<1$ which goes from the punctured unit disc to itself, and note that by boundness all $g_n$ extend to $0$ too; then Montel's theorem applies etc

Comment: @Conrad sorry I am not familiar with Montel's tgeorem, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem and references from there

Comment: @conrad Thank you.

Comment: From what I read we only need ghe boundedness, is the convergence at integer points necessary?